# Adding Alertview with coordinates of the Pressed place in Mapview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Im Having **MapView**.. I added this as a subview of ViewController's View. I have the following Code in ViewDidLoad:

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapLongPress:)]; 
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2; 
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [longPressGesture release];
```

And ,

```
- (void)mapLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"Gesture");
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        CGPoint touchLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate = [mapView convertPoint:touchLocation toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
```

These i Got from StackOverFlow.. But Its not Working.. Did i need to do anything more in that?

Comment: Does the mapLongPress: method is called? Can you able to print 'coordinate'?

Comment: No.. The Method not get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[self.view addSubview:mapView];` after `[mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapLongPress:)]; 
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2; 
longPressGesture.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
[longPressGesture release];
```

Comment: I get this ... How to display the coordinates in AlertView

Comment: Use this code after getting the coordinates.

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Coordinates" message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d, %d",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

Answer (score 1):

Just add the **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** to ViewController and do the above code given by me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;

[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

This is using ARC, so I am not sure if you should release the gesture at this moment right now. Try it without releasing it, then try it with releasing it. See if that affects the gesture.

Comment: Do u have idea diaplaying the following format in AlertView Latitude=XXX Longitude=YYY